# Cannot create a table in PHP

Tags: php, database, mysqli, connection

I've encountered a certain problem. I want to create a table in my database through PHP but it does not work properly.. Even though I copy the text which serves to create a database into PHPMYADMIN, it works perfectly there. Can anyone find any mistake? I have already checked my connection parameters.

```
    if(empty($errors)) {

    $namess = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['topicname']);

    mysqli_select_db($conn,"d197243_games");

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE {$namess} (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, topicname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, topicdescription VARCHAR(255), topictext TEXT ,primary key (id));";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$result) {
        $errors[] = 'Unknown error while creating a post.';
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there an error being thrown?

Comment: Unfortunately, no specific error has not been thrown.. Just mine for debuggining and that is stored in $errors[].

Comment: Please use `var_dump(mysqli_error($conn));` after your query and check what it says.

Comment: Find Error by 
if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)
  {
  echo ("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
  }

Comment: This is abit hard with the information we have, try to dd or var_dump. You may also try to close your mysqli function with try/catch to see the exceptions

Comment: Alright, I found my error. It cannot somehow access the database.

Error description: CREATE command denied to user 'w197243_games'@'...' for table..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query have you used

```
{$namess}
```

if yes then remove those flower brackets

and simply right **$namess**

as below

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $namess (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, topicname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, topicdescription VARCHAR(255), topictext TEXT ,primary key (id));";
```

and hope you have defined your table name in **$namess** varible

Comment: He used $namess and not $name, also he use the string literals. It should work fine with the brackets intact

Comment: I think this is not a problem I am encountering.

Comment: Also found one thing, I cannot use spaces because it writes another error

Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''654654545465465454654 5454 54654 645' (id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, topicnam' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I've solved it myself, and thanks for that ''show error'' command. It showed my problem. I have not had enough permissions to access the database.. I had to use different login credentials.. Anyways, thank you for your help & answers. Appriciate it.